# How to get browser fingerprint from clientJS in react application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, fingerprintjs2

I am trying to get the browser fingerprint from react application using clientJS. When I import clientJS module and try to access get fingerprint function, it's throwing error saying `Get Finger Print is not a function`. But If i create a clientJS instance from `window.ClientJS()`. I am able to generate the fingerprint. Why am i not able get the fingerprint function from instance of ClientJS?

**Not working**

```
import ClientJS from "clientjs";

const client = new ClientJS()

const fingerPrint = client.getFingerprint()
```

console.log(client)

[image]
**Working**

```
import ClientJS from "clientjs";

const client = new ClientJS()
const windowClient = new window.ClientJS();

const fingerPrint = windowClient.getFingerprint()
```

console.log(windowClient);

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done much with client Js but I have a tiny package I built that you can use to get a browser fingerprint with ease.

You can use it in any of your frontend application.

It is available here https://github.com/successtar/browser-signature

Comment: awesome package man but if i open an incognito window then the fingerprint changes. Any way to make the fingerprint constant?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in a react application

```
import ClientJS from 'clientjs'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

let clientJs: any

const MyComponent = () => {
   const [fingerprint, setFingerprint] = useState('')
   
   useEffect(() => {
     clientJs = new ClientJS()
   }, []) // initiate on the first load

   setFingerprint(clientJs.getFingerprint)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Code below is working for me in React.

```
import ClientJS from 'clientjs';

var client = new ClientJS();

client.getBrowser()
```